# Differentiate the equation: $y = x{(1 + 3x)^5}$ using product rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

After using the chain rule, I use the product rule and get dy/dx to be:

$15x{(1 + 3x)^4} + {(1 + 3x)^5}$

From then on I get stuck, i'm aware I need to expand and simplify further, but the answer in the textbook does this in a very easy manner that doesnt involve expanding brackets:

$\eqalign{
  &  = {(1 + 3x)^4}(15x + 1 + 3x)  \cr 
  &  = {(1 + 3x)^4}(1 + 18x) \cr} $

What is the reasoning behind this? What happens to the expression that goes to the power of 5?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question, but you could also do it without the product rule using $3y=(1+3x)^6-(1+3x)^5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that you gave: $15x{(1 + 3x)^4} + {(1 + 3x)^5}$ is correct.

Just take $(1+3x)^4$ common in the sum, then

$15x{(1 + 3x)^4} + {(1 + 3x)^5}
    = {(1 + 3x)^4}(15x + 1 + 3x)    = {(1 + 3x)^4}(1 + 18x) $

Comment: Thank you for your help! I feel very silly now given how obvious that was! Thanks!